# Swashbuckle Swagger Try It Out behind NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, swagger, nginx-reverse-proxy, swashbuckle

I'm trying to make the swaggerUI Try it out function to work behind NGINX reverse proxy.
I'm using ASP.net Core with the package `Swashbuckle Swagger`

Since I have multiple API I added a subdomain to my nginx config.

When I use try it out it sends the request to

`http://{server-ip-address}/api/myendpoint`

instead of

`http://{server-ip-address}/myapi/api/myendpoint`

My goal is to add the myapi to the address of Try it out function.
I'm not sure if I should edit my NGINX config or my ASP.net core configuration.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   ...
   app.UseSwagger(opt =>
    {
       opt.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
       {
            var serverUrl = $"http://{httpReq.Host}/myapi/api/myendpoint";
            swagger.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>{new() { Url = serverUrl }};
       });
    });
```

Comment: I modified it to  'var serverUrl = $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}/{prefix}"'. This way it handles HTTPS if needed.

Comment: Great job, my friend. We made it!